# Registry key setting to enable windows to download driver from windows update

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-update, drivers

I have to issue an update to software enable the setting shown in the picture below.

[image]

I have systems that are set to "Never install driver software from Windows Update". I was wondering if there is a registry entry corresponding to this setting so I can set it to either "Yes, do this automatically (recommended)" or "No, let me choose what to do" with "Install driver software from windows update if it's not found on my computer".

The closest thing I was able to find was [NoDevMgrUpdate](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1217/) but that did not seem to help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

I found it,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig"=dword:00000002
```

and here's a reference for `SearchOrderConfig`

```
SearchOrderConfig 0 = Yes, do this automatically
SearchOrderConfig 1 = No, let me choose what to do, Always install the best...
SearchOrderConfig 2 = No, let me choose what to do, Install driver software from windows update ...
SearchOrderConfig 3 = No, let me choose what to do, Never install driver software from Windows update
```

Comment: Make sure to include the `PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork` mentioned by @allgamer

Answer (score 5):

Actually the correct answer is:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
SearchOrderConfig 1 = No, let me choose what to do, Always install the best...
SearchOrderConfig 2 = No, let me choose what to do, Install driver software from windows update ...
SearchOrderConfig 3 = No, let me choose what to do, Never install driver software from Windows update
```

there is no actual SearchOrderConfig 0

the "zero" is trigerred automatically by a combination of registry keys **SearchOrderConfig** 1 + **PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork** 0, if you were to manually change SearchOrderConfig to zero, it does nothing if PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork is not enabled.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Device Metadata]
PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork 0 = enhanced icons enabled
PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork 1 = enhanced icons disabled
```

Comment: Verified with procmon. The exe to look for is newdev.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here are the correct settings for that reg key.

```
0 = "No, let me choose what to do - Never install driver software from Windows Update"
1 = "Yes, do this automatically (recommended)"
2 = "No, let me choose what to do - Install driver software from Windows Update if it is not found on my computer."
```

Those are the only options, since "No, let me choose what to do - Always install the best driver software from Windows Update" is pretty much identical to "Yes, do this automatically (recommended)."  I tested these each simply by choosing each setting available and then viewing the registry key after saving the changes.

Comment: This answer is not complete.

Comment: Yes, what is the registry key in question?

Comment: The registry key IS the one mentioned mentioned by shadowfoxmi -

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig"=dword:00000000

But the options are what I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this values are all dependent on which Version & build of Windows 10 is currently running on your machine.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 1511 Build 10586, and I tried setting value to 3 but the driver installation is still triggered which causes the installation to fail and I am stuck on Old windows version. Will try to change it to "0" and try again over the weekend and update my answer.

Note:- I have even disabled it in GroupPolicy, but the driver installation is still triggered.